# Can I read a file from different commits in parallel in Git repository?

Tags: git, duplicates

I am using `Git`, for versioning large files (when it is modified) and eliminate the duplication of the whole file. If possible, I want to read/access from the committed versions of that file in parallel.

**[Q]** Is this possible with the help of `Git`? If not, is there any other tool for this.

---

In this scenerio, assume that I have a single Git repository (A) that contains a large-file (`myFile.txt`) which is 10 GB and a binary code which uses `myFile.txt` during its run. I committed those files. Please note that I am not pushing it into Github.

```
$ cd A && ls 
 run // Assume it is a build source code that do some operation with myFile.txt and gives an output
 myfile.txt
$ git init
$ git add -N *
$ git commit -a -m "version1"
```

Later I made some modifications on `myFile.txt` added few lines and commited again.

```
$ git add -N *
$ git commit -a -m "version2"
[master 9fde555] version2
1 file changed, 100 insertions // Changed file is myFile.txt
```

---

At this point, I want to run two processes of my source-code (`run`) in parellel, where first job should interact with the `myFile.txt` on the committed *version-1* and second job should interact with the `myFile.txt` on the committed *version-2*.

I can easily copy `myFile.txt` on *version-2* into different folder and run my code reading from its copied location but this will create a duplication most parts of that file and I would require to store 10 GB all over again.

Comment: The very fact that a file is 10 GB is a NO No please re org your repo comments. Also what you are admin is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.  If your program can read from a stream, then it's pretty trivial:

```
git show <commit>:p/a/t/h/to/myFile.txt | run
```

Or, if you're using bash, perhaps you can do:

```
run <(git show <commit>:p/a/t/h/to/myFile.txt)
```

But if your program needs a regular file (eg, if it seeks), you'll probably need to have two copies of the file on disk.

Comment: Also since the program reads from `<commit>:/..` path, does program able to make changes on the file using stream writer @William Pursell

Comment: @alper No.  If you want to do things like that, you'll need to modify your program substantially.

Comment: Your program would not be reading from `<commit>:...`.  Rather, you are invoking git to generate a data stream from that path, and your program is reading from that stream.

Comment: On my case I want to read files from a specific commit in parallel. For that, I guess my only option is to have two copies of that file on the disk.   Is there any tool to achieve this? I was thinking about "block level file storage".